# secure file transfer over the internet

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, data-transfer

What is the best way to transfer files (secure data) over the internet? I am thinking about WCF REST services. The file size is less than 10MB.  Our company do not allow FTP transfer. Could you please suggest if there are any articles or third party tools? I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your on windows. From the command line you can use [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) which is PuTTY Secure Copy, there is a nice tutorial  [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) but the basic idea is:

`pscp myfile.txt hostname:/home/user/`

Another more comprehensive and user friendly (GUI) application is [winSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Comment: Is there any way we can send acknowledge message to sender?

Comment: If we use scp, do we have to open up the port from our network?

Answer (score 0):

As you included the C# tag, are you incorporate this into a program?

If so, check out the SharpSSH Library - http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Feature List
The following list summarizes the features currently supported by SharpSSH:

```
SharpSSH is pure .NET, but it depends on Mentalis.org Crypto Library for encryption and integrity functions.
SSH2 protocol support
SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
Secure Copy (SCP)
Key exchange: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Cipher: 3des-cbc, aes128-cbc
MAC: hmac-md5
Host key type: ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
Userauth: password, publickey (RSA, DSA)
Port Forwarding
Stream Forwarding
Remote Exec
Generating DSA and RSA key pairs
Changing the passphrase for a private key
```